# Why does my set_output_delay constraints cause warnings

Tags: constraints, fpga, intel-fpga

I am trying to understand some warnings I get in Altera's TimeQuest.
I started with the following constraints in my .sdc file

```
set_output_delay -clock clk -max 3 [get_ports {data[*]}]
set_output_delay -clock clk -min 1 [get_ports {data[*]}]
```

It gave me warnings like

```
set_output_delay has replaced one or more delays on port "data[0]". Please use -add_delay option.
```

My understanding was that even though a min and max delay is specified the second constraint will override the first constraint.

So I tried

```
set_output_delay -clock clk -max 3 [get_ports {data[*]}]
set_output_delay -clock clk -min 1 [get_ports {data[*]}] -add_delay
```

This still gave me the same warning as before. Only if I applied `add_delay` to both:

```
set_output_delay -clock clk -max 3 [get_ports {data[*]}] -add_delay
set_output_delay -clock clk -min 1 [get_ports {data[*]}] -add_delay
```

did the warning go away.

What I do not understand is why I get these warnings when I use `add_delay` only on the second min constraint. I have no other constraints for this port in the design.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the reason behind this.

The problem was that I reread the SDC file without first resetting the design. All the constraints got reapplied and of course there was warnings.

Resetting the design in TimeQuest and then rereading the SDC file did not cause any warnings.